# How to load of a Mongoengine document containing ReferenceField from kwargs

Tags: python, mongoengine, odm

Are there any examples of instantiating a Mongoengine Document with an attribute being a ReferenceField from kwargs ?

I am looking for the same test case as "test_kwargs_simple" @ https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/tests/document/instance.py#L2834

But replacing the EmbeddedDocument field by a ReferenceField.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just pass some `Document` like the `EmbeddedDocument` was in the test:

```py
class Referenced(Document):
    name = StringField()

class Doc(Document):
    doc_name = StringField()
    doc = ReferenceField(Referenced)

classic_doc = Doc(doc_name="my doc", doc=Referenced(name="referenced doc"))
```